# How can I embed PHP code in HTML?

Tags: nodes, 9

I want to execute few curl commands from my Drupal site using PHP.

Idea is to create a custom content type that accepts php code. I understood from the internet I have to create a file "node--page.tpl.php" and add the below code in this file.

1. Will this actually work?
2. If yes, at which path should I place node--page.tpl.php file?

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <Relavent Tags/>
    <title>My Page</title>
</head>
<body>
 <h3 style="text-align:center;">Heading</h3>

    <?php
$url = "Service Endpoint";

// Initializing curl
$curl = curl_init();

// Sending GET request to reqres.in
// server to get JSON data
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

// Telling curl to store JSON
// data in a variable instead
// of dumping on screen
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);    
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);

// Executing curl
$response = curl_exec($curl);

// Checking if any error occurs
// during request or not
if($e = curl_error($curl)) {
    echo $e;
} else {
    
    // Decoding JSON data
    $decodedData = json_decode($response, true);
        
    // Outputting JSON data in
    // Decoded form


   print_r($decodedData);
    
}

// Closing curl
curl_close($curl);
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: .tpl.php files are for Drupal 7. Drupal 9 uses .html.twig for template files which cannot execute PHP code.

Comment: Even on Drupal 7, adding that code in a template file would be a bad idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In answer to the questions you asked: No this will not work. Drupal 9 uses the Twig templating engine. You cannot execute arbitrary PHP code in Twig. Instead you should write a Drupal module.

Comment: Can you please help with the documentation to create a custom for this scenario?

Comment: The rules of this site forbid asking about tutorials, documentation, modules, themes, or distributions you need to find or you ask us to recommend or suggest.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, the module route is preferred. Pasting PHP code into content type presents a security risk and should be avoided at all costs.